# Unable to reach the website using selenium with proxy in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to connect to a website using Selenium in Python. The script works perfectly when I don't use any proxy. However, when I try to re-run the script again with Proxy then I get `ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED` and the page isn't displayed. Below is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['proxy']={
    "httpProxy":PROXY,
    "ftpProxy":PROXY,
    "sslProxy":PROXY,

    "proxyType":"MANUAL",

}
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='../chromedriver.exe')
browser.get('https://www.facebook.com')
```

Is there a solution to get past this error code? The only thing new that is added is the `webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME` where `PROXY` is added. If I don't use this then the script works just fine. I am unable to understand what I may be doing wrong here.

Comment: How do you the proxy is actually working or not? You should manually configure the proxy and see if it actually works for you or not

Comment: I am using this to get the proxies: https://free-proxy-list.net/

Comment: Lot of those proxies don't work. So test then using some online tester like https://hidemy.name/en/proxy-checker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting indicates that the proxy doesn't work. Best way is to make sure you test your proxies with an online proxy test tool

One such tool is below

https://hidemy.name/en/proxy-checker/